# Epson ink tank L310 and Epson ink tank L120 Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and I am thinking of buying Epson ink tank L310 or Epson ink tank L120.

Do they have compatible drivers on Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Yes, they do. http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModuleFromResult

Comment: @Pilot6 I guess that's the answer...

Comment: @Zanna I am not quite sure the question is on-topic ;-)

Comment: @Pilot6 seems fine to me! +1 to the answer and the question too

Answer (score 2):

Both printers have drivers for Ubuntu.

They can be found at the [Epson Drivers Site](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule)

They are also available in Ubuntu repositories. If you just add a new printer, most likely the drivers will be installed automatically.

I am not quite sure that the `precise` repos have all new drivers, but anyway if the drivers are not installed automatically, you can always install them manually.